# Volusion Soft Add To Cart - Show cart Total instead of Subtotal

Tags: cart, volusion

In the Volusion shopping carts "soft add to cart" feature, which is turned on in product options with "Enable Add To Cart Popup", the popup shows the "Subtotal" of products currently in the cart.

The issue is this Subtotal does not include quantity discounts and therefore shows customers a higher price than the actual Subtotal after discounts are applied.

For that reason, we would like to display the cart Total, which includes any quantity discounts applied.

The problem is, I cannot find a place where this can be done in the HTML we have access to and if I were to find it, I'm not sure of the proper Volusion syntax to use to call up the Total instead of the Subtotal.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue, but the same problem (soft add to cart did not display the proper info).

In my case, we allow engraving on our products, for an additional charge, and when selected this option was not displayed in the popup cart.  As a result, customers were not sure if they chose it or not.

My solution was to add a Shopping Cart block to the page, as part of the template, using jQuery.

If you call http://yourUrl/AjaxCart.asp you'll see the discount info you need in the JSON data, as well as the line items in the order.